# c++ runtime error? how to solve this and check?

Tags: c++, memory, gcc, runtime

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hash, opp, i, j, c = 0;

    //cout<<"enter hasmat army number and opponent number\n";
    while(cin>>hash>>opp)
    {
        cout<<opp-hash<<endl;
    }
}
```

time limit for this problem: 3.000 seconds 
how can i verify and test this condition?

i'm submitting this to a computer online, how exactly can i know run time error? should i calculate run time and memory?

explain me how to check runtime and memory in c++ in linux, i'm using gcc version 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9).

Comment: That is more specific or the contest you are submitting the code to. Check what situations are considered as 'runtime error' in that particular contest.

Comment: Please specify: does it say run-time error (your program crashes) or does it exceed the time limit? E.g SPOJ would give you feedback of this kind. If it is a runtime error, you'd need to make sure your program doesn't contain bugs / undefined behavior, you've understood the problem description and your code can also handle less obvious corner cases. If it exceeds time limit, you'd probably need to consider whether you are using an algorithm with adequate complexity for the task (and not doing things generally in suboptimal ways).

Comment: I see that you're using I/O, and from standard input.  Where is the input coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've compiled your program, check its running time by running it with the Unix program `time`:

```
time ./myprogram
```

This will print how much "real" (human) time was taken, and how much CPU (active processing) time.

If you want to check how much memory your program uses, run it in the debugger and set a breakpoint where you want to inspect the memory usage, or just put a long `sleep()` in your code and run it without the debugger.  Then you can use tools like `ps` or `top` to see how much memory (virtual, resident, etc.) is in use by your program.